# Device stuck in a bootloop

Tags: recovery-mode, boot-loop, dalvik-cache

My Samsung Galaxy J7 SM-J700F is stuck in a bootloop after flashing. Now I need to clear cache, but my volume buttons are broken, can someone please help me to resolve this?

UPD: Somehow managed to enter download mode by a safety pin, any ideas what I should do next? I had a custom rom installed and I flashed a stock rom after which the bootloop started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your device if you can't fix the buttons in order to enter recovery/fastboot mode, you'll have to use Odin tool combined with download mode which you've successfully entered.
Odin is a tool made for flashing the original firmware of Samsung devices, it is being used to fix any sort of bricking, whether hard or soft bricking. If you have a PC/laptop, just download Odin tool form a trusted website, download your device complete and specific firmware from a supported website and then follow the steps in flashing your Samsung device using Odin tool from a tutorial. I don't currently own any Samsung device, so I don't have any links for the resources needed, but if you do your research, you'll find all the resources needed to flash your samsung device using Odin mode, as it is popularly called.

That's all you need to do in fixing your Samsung device. Good luck .

NB: Odin is the popular tool for flashing Samsung android devices in download mode, that's why it's usually called Odin mode.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).